# different output from rails queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a user (`User`) model which has many questions (`Question`). Each user has a unique key. The question model has a field to store that key. I need to search for all the questions by a specific user.

After adding two questions, when I query:

```
my_user.questions
```

it only returns 1 question. But, when I query:

```
Question.where(:key => "user-key")
```

it *does* return both.

I can't seem to figure out why they have different results. Any ideas?

Comment: To figure out what is going on you may want to have a look at your log to see the difference between the SQL for each of these scenarios.

Comment: And it would be hard for anyone else to figure out what's the problem by guessing how your code looks like :P Put the code for both models and the db schema and we may be able to help. When you do my_user.questions, the query will use the foreign key **user_id** on the question by default, unless you tell activerecord that the relationship should be built by any other column.

Comment: Im not at the privilege put up the code. I'm working on an app for some1. My basic question is that shouldn't these two queries give out the same result theoratically or it depends on the schema. I'm a newbie to rails :p